# jQuery get the "event invoking" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, methods, invoke

My problem is that when the checkbox below is clicked - the check function is called to check/uncheck all the checkboxes. But they have to change relatively to the invoking checkbox (the one with the "onchange" event).

The checkbox HTML declaration:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="$('input[type=checkbox][rel=users]').check();">
```

Sample JavaScript Code:

```
$.fn.check = function() {
    $(this).each(function(){
        $(this).attr('checked', checked);
    });
}
```

And my question is: How can I get the DOM object corresponding to the "check all" checkbox?

Comment: i do not really get your question, could you please go in detail? what are you meaning by relatively invoking?

Comment: When the root one is checked - all of the others should go checked and when it is not all of the others should be unchecked.

Comment: @ItehnologicalDisexisting - You should avoid using event attributes like `onchange` at all costs.

Comment: Why is that? It works in all browsers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Pass the `this` object of the checkAll to the function.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/nC6MG/1/)

```
<input type="checkbox" 
   onchange="$('input[type=checkbox][rel=users]').check(this);" />
```

Note the `this` is passed as `.check(this)`

And in the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.check = function(orgEl) {
        $(this).each(function() {
            $(this).attr('checked', orgEl.checked);
        });
    }
});
```

### Old Post -

Bind the checkAll checkbox to an handler and call the fxn from inside.. See below,

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" >
```

**JS**

```
   $(document).ready (function () {
       $('#checkAll').click (function () {
          //this inside is checkAll checkbox object.
          $('input[type=checkbox][rel=users]').check();
       });
   });
```

Comment: Yes, sure - that would work perfectly for the case, but I want to use the script as a library so it has to do it automatically. Is there a way for that?

Comment: @ItehnologicalDisexisting See updated answer and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're binding this to the "checkall" checkbox, you have access to itself inline. So you can pass it to the jQuery `.check()` function you made and use it there. Look at this:
(please excuse my changes to your selecting, you can obviously use what you had before...but I would suggest using `:checkbox` instead of `input[type=checkbox]`)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.fn.check = function (obj) {
            $(this).each(function (){
                this.checked = obj.checked;
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkall" onclick="$('.check-item').check(this);" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-item" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-item" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-item" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-item" /><br />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check-item" /><br />
<body>
```

Comment: Also, let it be known you should be using "onclick" of the checkbox instead of "onchange". Older IE browsers (I can't remember if all) don't work with "onchange".

Answer (score 1):

**[View on JSFIDDLE.](http://jsfiddle.net/bryandowning/9pF3d/)**

I'm a fan of using HTML5 data attributes for stuff like this. With the following DOM structure, you can define your target checkboxes with a `data-target` attribute on the triggering checkbox. The target should be a valid jQuery selector string.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkUsers" class="checkAll" data-target="input[type=checkbox][rel=users]">

<label for="checkUsers">Users:</label>

<input type="checkbox" rel="users">
<input type="checkbox" rel="users">
<input type="checkbox" rel="users">
<input type="checkbox" rel="users">
<input type="checkbox" rel="users">


<br><br>


<input type="checkbox" id="checkPlaces" class="checkAll" data-target="input[type=checkbox][rel=places]">

<label for="checkPlaces">Places:</label>

<input type="checkbox" rel="places">
<input type="checkbox" rel="places">
<input type="checkbox" rel="places">
<input type="checkbox" rel="places">
<input type="checkbox" rel="places">
```

Then you setup the plugin to use the target you defined to trigger the checks/unchecks based on the triggering checkbox's checked attribute.

**Plugin:**

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.check = function() {  

    // "this" is a jQuery object of the checkbox that was clicked.
    var target = this.data("target");
    $(target).attr("checked", this[0].checked);

    return this; //maintain chainability

  };

})( jQuery );
```

The real benefit of this method is that it allows you to only have to manage one event handler declaration by attaching the event to a `class` instead of an `id`.

**Event Handler Declaration:**

```
$(function(){

    $(".checkAll").click(function(){
        $(this).check();
    });

});
```

Comment: Awesome. I am 100% voting on this response for it's quality, but in my case I need to be sure that my app will work on all browsers, so HTML5 is not really an option.

Comment: @Itehnological - using the data attributes will not cause issues in other browsers. Because JavaScript is the only thing that is using them, they will not affect layout or break in any way that I'm aware of. As you can see, jQuery already natively handles the processing of these data attributes with the `.data()` method. This has not always been the case with jQuery. You used to have to use a plugin called the metadata plugin to achieve such functionality. In short, don't let HTML5 scare you away! Even the new tags introduced in HTML5 can be easily made to work in most common browsers.